# Always charge shipping for some items, even with rule "Free shipping for orders above $xx"

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I have an ecommerce and there's a little thing haunting me for the past few days.

I would like to give my customers FREE SHIPPING on orders above $50 (or 100, 150. Doesn't really matter.)

But *on some specific items* I will ALWAYS charge the shipping, so it should overwrite the Free Shipping rule.

Example:

- Item A ($40) added to the cart => Cart Total = $40 => NO FREE SHIPPING
- Item B ($30) added to the cart => Cart Total = $70 => FREE SHIPPING
- Item C should always charge shipping. So if Item C ($5) is added to the cart, the new cart value should  be:
  $40 + $30 + $5 + SHIPPING for item C.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: It's a brand new store. I don't use any plugins for shipping and I don't have any classes yet. I've created some for testing purposes but did not achieve what I wanted.

Comment: I want to be able to give free shipping above a certain order value. However some few items should always charge for shipping, even if the rule of free shipping is applied. There is no further going that would change this scenario. Website is up and running, this is the only thing lefting.

Comment: Some additional info that may help: I only ship to a specific country and I have only one shipping method. I will always charge FLAT RATE on items. On orders above $50 the customer gets free shipping. However, for some specific items the shipping will still be charged, even if the rest of the order has free shipping. Is that clear? I don't know how can I explain it any other way, sorry.